# Adding align property in CSS2.0

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, css

I have a table , and the style for one particular td is

```
<td style="vertical-align: middle;align: center!important; height: 200px; background-color: #ffffff;text-align: -moz-center!important;width: 180px;">
```

The problem is , if I use `text-align:center` , it is working fine for `Document Mode :`IE7. But if I change the document mode to `IE9`. The alignment is in left.Then I used developer tool to test it. If I use `align:center` , it is working fine for both document modes.
Now when I tried to add it in my code, it showing CSS warning that `"align is not a known CSS property name"`. Eventhough If I suppress the warning, when I execute the code the align atrribute is not adding in my style.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this ?

Comment: now what do you want to do ?

Comment: @Usman I want to add align:center in my code so that it will support both IE7 and IE9 document mode. Even If I add it in the code, after executing,I am not able to see that attribute in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`align="center"` is used like that,

```
<td align="center">text</td>
```

`text-align:center` is used in style="..."

```
<td align="center" style="text-align:center">text</td>
```

Use this,

```
<td align="center" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align:center; height: 200px; background-color: #ccc;text-align: -moz-center!important;width: 180px;">
```